# PULP: Check variable setting against constraints

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, pulp

I'm looking to set up a constraint-check in Python using PULP. Suppose I had variables A1,..,Xn and a constraint (AffineExpression) A1X1 + ... + AnXn <= B, where A1,..,An and B are all constants.

Given an assignment for X (e.g. X1=1, X2=4,...Xn=2), how can I check if the constraints are satisfied? I know how to do this with matrices using Numpy, but wondering if it's possible to do using PULP to let the library handle the work.

My hope here is that I can check specific variable assignments. I do not want to run an optimization algorithm on the problem (e.g. prob.solve()).

Can PULP do this? Is there a different Python library that would be better? I've thought about Google's OR-Tools but have found the documentation is a little bit harder to parse through than PULP's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is possible doing the following:

1. Define PULP variables and constraints and add them to an LpProblem
2. Make a dictionary of your assignments in the form {'variable name': value}
3. Use LpProblem.assignVarsVals(your_assignment_dict) to assign those values
4. Run LpProblem.valid() to check that your assignment meets all constraints and variable restrictions

Note that this will almost certainly be slower than using numpy and Ax <= b. Formulating the problem might be easier, but performance will suffer due to how PULP runs these checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can stay in numpy and accomplish this. Looking at a single line from a matrix you can set your row of **A** equal to a vector and then create a row sum that allows you to check the index and find if it is true. For example:

```
a = A[0, :]
row_sum = a*x
sum(row_sum) <= B[0]
```

The last line will return just `True` or `False`. Then if you want to change a single index you could update your `row_sum` array by using

```
row_sum[3] = a[3]*new_val
```

and run your analysis again.

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear, I want to do this using PULP or another optimization library, not numpy. The reason is that I expect to have many constraints and PULP makes it a lot easier to construct these than doing it by hand with matrices